# Updating multiple data at once in two different table in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I want to update multiple data at once in two different table, lets just call it table1 and table2. On table1 I have 3 columns, id, detail_id, and program_name. On table2 I also have 3 columns, id, age, and detail_program. I can store the data from user input into database using this code

```php
$detailId = [];

foreach($request['age'] as $key => $ages) {
    $programDetails = ProgramDetail::create([
        'age' => $ages,
        'detail_program' => $request['detail_program'][$key]
    ]);
    $detailId[] = $programDetails->id;
}

$detailId_string = implode(',', $detailId);

ProgramVaksin::create([
    'detail_id' => $detailId_string,
    'program_name' => $request->program_name
]);
```

But when I try to update the data, It can update and return success message, but the data is not what user inputting. For example, user want to change the age data that has detail_id 20,30, and 40 from 1, 2, 3 become 3, 4, 5. After the user click the update button, the age data that user inputting it's become random. Like it should be 3, 4, 5 but it's become 5, 4, 4 or 4, 5, 5 or nothing change at all. This is my code for updating data

```php
public function update(Request $request, ProgramVaksin $programVaksin)
{
    $age = $request->input('age');
    $detail = $request->input('detail_program');

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($age); $i++) {
        ProgramDetail::where('id', $programVaksin->detail_id[$i])->update([
            'age' => $age[$i],
            'detail_program' => $detail[$i]
        ]);
    }

    ProgramVaksin::where('id', $programVaksin->id)->update([
        'program_name' => $request->program_name
    ]);

    return redirect('/dashboard/program-vaksin')->with('success', 'Data has been updated');
}
```

Can someone help me about this?

Comment: `dd($age)` to check what you get from the request. also make sure `$programVaksin->detail_id[$i]` is valid.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I did the dd($age) and I got an array where the inside of it is a number, but with a double quotes like this ["2", "1", "3"] and I think the $programVaksin->detail_id[$i} is valid, but how to check it?

Answer (score 0):

If `$age` is an array, you could make a collection from it and get a random element on each update.

```php
$ages = collect($request->input('age', [])); // if no age is present, at least have an empty array
$detail = $request->input('detail_program');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($ages); $i++) {
    ProgramDetail::where('id', $programVaksin->detail_id[$i])->update([
        'age' => $ages->random(),
        'detail_program' => $detail[$i]
    ]);
}
```

If you want to use pure php methods, there's also [`array_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

```php
$ages = $request->input('age', []); // if no age is present, at least have an empty array
$detail = $request->input('detail_program');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($ages); $i++) {
    ProgramDetail::where('id', $programVaksin->detail_id[$i])->update([
        'age' => $ages[array_rand($ages)],
        'detail_program' => $detail[$i]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I have try your answer, but it's still the same. Nothing change in the database